# surface area in a basin with reference to incremental height of DAM

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst, volume, surface

I want to calculate "surface area in a basin with reference to incremental height of DAM"

i tried this:

```
step_size = 10 # metres; reduce this if you want finer resolution
num_steps = 20 # increase this, if you need more steps
workspace = r'C:\Some\path\to\folder'
raster_file = 'mytopo.tif'

gp = arcgisscripting.create()
gp.CheckOutExtension ('3D')
gp.workspace = workspace

# Start from the minimum elevation
min_rast = gp.GetRasterProperties(raster_file, 'MINIMUM')

# Start CSV output of elevation/volume relationship
print('step, height, elev, volume')
for step in range(num_steps):
    height = float(step*step_size)
    elev = min_rast + height
    gp.SurfaceVolume_3d(raster_file, '', 'BELOW', elev)
    result = gp.GetMessages()
    volume = float(re.findall(r'Volume= *([\d\.]+)', result)[0])
    print(', '.join([repr(x) for x in [step + 1, height, elev, volume]]))
```

Can you help me edit this code to get volume to get surface area?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you please *edit* your question and be more specific what you have done so far and about the nature of your datasets. The question is very broad and it is unlikely that we are able to help you.

Comment: What happens when you run the code snippet that you have presented?